# Custom RMSE loss not the same as taking the root of built-in Keras MSE loss

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, mse, rms

I have defined a custom RMSE loss function:

```
def rmse(y_pred, y_true):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true)))
```

I was evaluating it against the mean squared error loss provided by Keras:

`keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)`

The values I get for MSE and RMSE respectively for some prediction are:

`mse: 115.7218 - rmse: 8.0966`

Now, when I take the root of the MSE, I get `10.7574`, which is obviously higher than the RMSE the custom loss function outputs. I haven't been able to figure out why this is so, nor have I found any related posts on this particular topic. Is there maybe a mistake in the RMSE loss function that I'm simply not seeing? Or is it somehow related to how Keras defines `axis=-1` in the MSE loss function (purpose of which I haven't fully understood yet)?

Comment: Can you show what tensors you used to get these results and the code you used to invoke the methods? Thanks.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would guess that you may have made an error in the order in which you fed the tensors. Notice Keras function call is `mse(y_true, y_pred)` rather than your order `rmse(y_pred, y_true)`

Comment: shouldn't the whole "squaring" part of this make the order arbitrary?